Error populating dropdown: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')
I'm using Tom Select for one of my dropdowns in the form. The form has an option to dynamically add new rows to the form. The Tom Select works perfectly fine for the default row of the form, but it breaks when I add a new row by clicking on the button. additionally, it shows the error below.

Error populating dropdown: TypeError: Cannot read properties of
undefined (reading 'trim')

Here is my script. could you have any solution for this. I'm new to Javascript & Jquery.
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Initialize Tom Select for the default product dropdown
    initializeTomSelect('.product_id', true);

    // Add new row functionality
    $('#add_expense_row').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Clone the row template
        const newRow = $('#aod_line').clone();
        newRow.removeAttr('id'); // Remove the ID to avoid duplication
        newRow.find('input[type="number"], input[type="text"]').val(''); // Clear input values
        newRow.find('.product_id').empty(); // Clear existing options
        newRow.find('.product_id').append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select a product</option>'); // Add placeholder
        newRow.find('#remove-line').prop('disabled', false); // Enable remove button

        // Append the new row
        $('#submit_div').before(newRow);

        // Initialize Tom Select for the newly added dropdown after populating options
        const productDropdown = newRow.find('.product_id');
        initializeTomSelect(productDropdown, false);
    });

    // Remove row functionality
    $(document).on('click', '#remove-line', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    });

    // Function to initialize Tom Select
    function initializeTomSelect(selector, isStatic = false) {
        $(selector).each(function () {
            const dropdown = $(this);

            // Populate options first before initializing Tom Select
            populateProductDropdown(dropdown).then(() => {
                console.log('Dropdown after population:', dropdown.html());
                
                if (!dropdown[0].tomselect) { // Check if Tom Select is already initialized
                    new TomSelect(dropdown[0], {
                        placeholder: 'Select a product',
                        allowEmptyOption: true, // Allow empty dropdowns to prevent errors
                    });
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error populating dropdown:', error);
            });
        });
    }

    // Function to populate product dropdown with products
    function populateProductDropdown(dropdown) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../controller/operations_controller.php?status=get-products',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    const select = dropdown[0].tomselect;

                    if (select) {
                        // If Tom Select is already initialized
                        select.clearOptions(); // Clear existing options
                        select.addOption({ value: '', text: 'Select a product', disabled: true }); // Add placeholder

                        data.forEach((product) => {
                            select.addOption({ value: product.product_id, text: product.product_name });
                        });
                        select.refreshOptions(false); // Refresh without opening
                    } else {
                        // If Tom Select is not initialized yet
                        dropdown.empty();
                        dropdown.append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select a product</option>'); // Add placeholder

                        data.forEach((product) => {
                            dropdown.append(`<option value="${product.product_id}">${product.product_name}</option>`);
                        });
                    }

                    resolve(); // Resolve the promise after population
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('AJAX error:', xhr.responseText || error);
                    alert('Failed to load products. Please try again later.');
                    reject(error); // Reject the promise on error
                }
            });
        });
    }
});

Here are two screenshots of the first row and the second row which was added dynamically.
https://imgur.com/a/EbTM3Wa

The script is where exactly :) Well, it would be nice to see the script, but the error you're seeing is from passing undefined to the tom-select package. It probably sanitizes the input behind the scenes (hence the error accessing String.trim).

Apologies for the confusion. I have updated the script.
